# Any alternative to bindGlBufferToTensor in Tensorflow Lite 2.0+?

Tags: android, camera, opencl, tensorflow-lite

I am developing an app, which tries to apply network inference to camera output in realtime. The most "advanced" technique I could find in tutorials was to capture the camera frame via GlSurfaceView, dump the frame into SSBO with some simple OpenCL shader, then run inference, setting SSBO as an input tensor.

However, the last version of Tensorflow Lite, featuring GpuDelegate.bindGlBufferToTensor(), was 1.14. Then, this API was removed with the comment like "*no problem breaking the clients, was an experimental API anyways...*". That was, well, discouraging...

So, what is the recommended way to use OpenGL data as tensor in Tensorflow Lite 2.0? I bet, applying NN to live camera view is among the most popular scenarios on mobile devices, but unfortunately, most tutorials refer to this SSBO magic, which is not available anymore. Or is it?